# API misinterpreting a password with special characters

Tags: python, authentication, http-headers

I use a Python code to connect to an API to retrieve information in JSON format. A password is used for the authentication to the API. The authentication was working fine so far, but since I changed my password into one with special characters, things went wrong. I guess the password is not well handled either by the API or the code I use.

This is the piece of code that seems to cause the errors:

```
# Create connection and request header.
# This class does not perform any verification of the server`s certificate.
conn = HTTPSConnection(ADDRESS)
auth_header = 'Basic %s' % (':'.join([USER_NAME, PASSWORD]).encode('Base64').strip('\r\n'))
request_header = {'Authorization':auth_header.decode(),
                'Content-Type': content_type}
```

The error I get after executing the code is the following:

```
    response = self.perform_request(log, 'GET', 'network', params=query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/query_code.py", line 103, in perform_request
    auth_header = 'Basic %s' % str(":".join([USER_NAME, PASSWORD]).encode('Base64').strip('\r\n'))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found
```

I should have had a successful connection to the API with code 200 and results returned in JSON format.

I have difficulties spotting the origin of all this, and would like to have your opinion on what I think it is, and how to solve it.

Comment: probably `PASSWORD` here is `None` -- you should check the code that you expect to be setting this variable

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
def basic_token(key, secret):
    return base64.b64encode(bytes(f'{key}:{secret}', 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

auth_header = f'basic {basic_token(USERNAME, PASSWORD)}'
```

If you are using a python version < 3.6, you will need to use `.format` instead of `f-strings`:

```
def basic_token(key, secret):
    return base64.b64encode(bytes('{}:{}'.format(key, secret), 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

auth_header = 'basic {}'.format(basic_token(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
```